# URL rewrite - Perl Regex

Tags: regex, perl, url-rewriting

I am trying to come up with rewrite rules for my site:

I tackled a couple simple one-to-one redirects. But In this case I haven't been able to.

Here is what I am trying to do:

`www.mydomain.con/industries/accounting/<anything>` should redirect to `www.mydomain.con/industries/accounting`

`www.mydomain.con/industries/healthcare/<anything>` should redirect to `www.mydomain.con/industries/healthcare`

I came up with this:

```
 RewriteRule ^/industries/(?:(?:accounting|healthcare)(/[-A-Za-z0-9_]*)+)$  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It just appends `<anything>` to the at the end and url becomes

```
www.mydomain.com/industries/<anything>
```

I do not want this to trigger when ever there some thing after accounting and/or healthcare and redirect it back to accounting or healthcare respectively.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(industries/(?:accounting|healthcare))/.+$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Not sure why you have `resources` in target URL.